# Ubuntu and Recoveries

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Does Ubuntu Touch overwrite a custom recovery (specifically CWM)?
I have not installed Ubuntu.on my phone yet due to the fact that Ubuntu Touch is still a work in progress for the Atrix 4G

Thanks for all your help
TheAndroidDude

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch will not overwrite a custom recovery.
There is a recovery file provided with the developer preview although I am not sure what it does and I'd recommend not using it.